# Switching Google Voice typing language and force offline mode?

Tags: google, languages, voice-recognition, offline

I've been using Google Voice for quite some time as it's fast and convenient compared to typing on the phone keyboard. However, I speak multiple languages and when I use the Google Voice software, if I enable different languages, the software is supposed to "auto detect" the language I speak but it makes mistakes all the time.

One way for me to get around this is to only select the language I want to speak in and deselect the other languages, but it gets tedious to do. There are a lot of languages that Google Voice support now and to search for the language I want to speak can be a bit of a pain when I need to reply to several messages in a short amount of time in different languages.

My understand is that there is no "long press" or a simple "language toggle" button for Google Voice typing, but is there any way to set something like "favorite languages" so they can be displayed at the top so the languages are easier to find? I remember some of the older versions of Google Voice will go by the keyboard language that's on, so as I switch the keyboard language, Google Voice will only be picking up what I say in that language, which worked out much better for me.

At the same time, I notice that when I don't have the best internet connection, it can take FOREVER for the Google Voice typing to work. If I go offline (airplane mode, turn off data, etc.) then it works great because Google Voice goes to offline mode. Is there any way to force the phone to always be in offline mode for Google Voice Typing? Since we can download each diction library offline already, I would hope there's a way or some kind of code that can force the software to use the offline library rather than trying to connect to the server every time.

Thanks for any input. Hope this can help some others in similar situations as well.

Comment: As for forcing offline mode, [I've asked for that about 2 years ago](/q/145105/16575) and didn't get an answer yet. If you manage to solve that part, I'd appreciate a "ping" (or maybe an answer on the linked question ;) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest one can switch between languages is tapping on the world icon:

[image]

Screenshot from Google Pixel 6 on Android 12  with Google keyboard.